# dir? or any command followed by "?" yields a + sign. Why?

Tags: r

Just experimenting with help in RStudio. So I type setwd? and the help comes up in another RStudio window. Now I type ls? ( at the console ) and all I get is "+". What's it expecting? I was told you don't need to put the () in and even if you do, same thing happens.  I have to escape out of it. Shut down and startup...same problem and same ole' output from setwd?.

I'm on a MacBook air M1 macOS BigSur 11.3.1

Comment: Put the question mark before the function: `?ls()`.

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting a string/object after the ? to search the prior type of files for. The characters before the ? it is treating as a type. If nothing is before the ? it searches all types of documentation: objects, packages, etc. Examples:

```
Is?is
Error in `?`(Is, is) : 
  no documentation of type ‘Is’ and topic ‘is’ (or error in processing help)

?"is"

?is

package?methods
```